# Typed the code but it is not showing the GUI components

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a small application using Java Swing concept. But facing some issues.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FirstFrame extends JFrame {

           JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
           JButton student,staff,trainer,admin;
           JPanel p;
           //Button b;

           public FirstFrame() {
               setTitle("SPARK-DB");
               setSize(1500,1000);
               setLayout(null);
               setVisible(true);
               p = new JPanel();
               p.setSize(1500,1000);
               p.setLayout(null);
               add(p);
               l1 = new JLabel("WELCOME TO SPARK DB");
               //jLabel1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
               l1.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
               l1.setBounds(700, 950, 400, 40);
               p.add(l1);

               l2 = new JLabel("CREATED BY : ANUP TIWARY AND MEHUL DUBEY");
               l2.setBounds(600, 900, 500, 30);
               p.add(l2);

               l3 = new JLabel("SELECT LOGIN TYPE");
               l3.setBounds(700,800, 400, 50);
               p.add(l3);

           }

       }
```

The above code does not show the labels created. I am not able to figure out what is missing here.

Comment: 1) **Only set the GUI visible once the components have been added.** Special measures are required to make components visible if added after that. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Given the 4 extra buttons and the gaping space in the GUI (even once the last label has been shoved upwards into view), I'm guessing there was more to this GUI. I'll show you how to position them using layouts, but first need to know how the GUI is **supposed** to look. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score -1):

The y value is beyond the visible space of a typical monitor. To fix the issue you need to reduce your y coordinate, for example 950 to 95.

```
l1.setBounds(700, 950, 400, 40);
```

I assume this is just a test code though. null layout is not recommended and ideally you should use one of the available layout managers.